# Regex: How to get a group name

Tags: .net, regex

I have a .NET Regex which looks similar to:

```
(?<Type1>AAA)|(?<Type2>BBB)
```

I'm using the *Matches* method against a sample string e.g. `"AAABBBAAA"`, and then iterating over the matches.

My goal is to find the match types, using the regex match group, so for this regex it will be:

- Type1
- Type2
- Type1

I couldn't find any `GetGroupName` method. Please help.

Answer (score 20):

Is this the sort of thing you're looking for? It uses [`Regex.GroupNameFromNumber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.groupnamefromnumber.aspx) so you don't need to know the group names outside the regex itself.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("(?<Type1>AAA)|(?<Type2>BBB)");
        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches("AAABBBAAA"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Next match:");
            GroupCollection collection = match.Groups;
            // Note that group 0 is always the whole match
            for (int i = 1; i < collection.Count; i++)
            {
                Group group = collection[i];
                string name = regex.GroupNameFromNumber(i);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2}", name, 
                                  group.Success, group.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to retrieve a specific group name you can use the [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)`.`[`GroupNameFromNumber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.groupnamefromnumber.aspx) method.

```
//regular expression with a named group
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<Type1>AAA)|(?<Type2>BBB)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

//evaluate results of Regex and for each match
foreach (Match m in regex.Matches("AAABBBAAA"))
{
    //loop through all the groups in current match
    for(int x = 1; x < m.Groups.Count; x ++)
    {
        //print the names wherever there is a succesful match
        if(m.Group[x].Success)
            Console.WriteLine(regex.GroupNameFromNumber(x));
    }
}
```

Also, There is a string indexer on the [`GroupCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.groupcollection.aspx). object that is accesible on the [`Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx)`.`[`Groups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx) property, this allows you to access a group in a match by name instead of by index.

```
//regular expression with a named group
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<Type1>AAA)|(?<Type2>BBB)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

//evaluate results of Regex and for each match
foreach (Match m in regex.Matches("AAABBBAAA"))
{
    //print the value of the named group
    if(m.Groups["Type1"].Success)
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["Type1"].Value);
    if(m.Groups["Type2"].Success)
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["Type2"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        var regex = new Regex("(?<Type1>AAA)|(?<Type2>BBB)");
        var input = "AAABBBAAA";
        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(input))
        {
            Console.Write(match.Value);
            Console.Write(": ");
            for (int i = 1; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
            {
                var group = match.Groups[i];
                if (group.Success)
                    Console.WriteLine(regex.GroupNameFromNumber(i));
            }    
        }
```