# RegEx Capturing Groups in C#

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to parse a file's contents using regex, but the patter I came up with doesn't seem to work.

The regex I am trying to use is

```cs
string regex = @"^(?<key>\w+?)\s*?:\s*?{(?<value>[\s\S]+?)}$";
```

and the text i am trying to parse it against is

```cs
string text = @"key:{value}
key:{valu{0}e}
key:{valu
{0}e}
key:{val-u{0}e}
key:{val__[!]
-u{0}{1}e}";
```

However, it returns 0 results

```cs
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, regex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

I have tried testing this regex on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/4e7eq), which worked as expected.
I am unsure why this doesn't work when trying it in C#.

MCVE:

```cs
string regex = @"^(?<key>\w+?)\s*?:\s*?{(?<value>[\s\S]+?)}$";
string text = @"key:{value}
key:{valu{0}e}
key:{valu
{0}e}
key:{val-u{0}e}
key:{val__[!]
-u{0}{1}e}";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, regex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
Console.WriteLine(matches.Count);
```

Comment: As noted by Luuk, the regex you've provided works with the text you've provided. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @jonskeet

The regex is used here: https://github.com/SMLHelper/SMLHelper/blob/LangOverrideBug/SMLHelper/Patchers/LanguagePatcher.cs#L107-L128

As for a mcve, I've updated my original question

Comment: Right - that code prints 1, not 0. So please provide an example that *actually* prints 0... or if you're in an unusual environment (which might have a broken regex implementation) please provide details of that.

Comment: At least, it prints 1 on my Windows machine, using CR/LF line breaks. If you change it to just LF line breaks, it prints 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way we might like to try is to test that if our expression would be working in another language.

Also, we might want to simplify our expression:

```
^(.*?)([\s:]+)?{([\s\S].*)?.$
```

where we have three capturing groups. The first and third ones are our desired key and values.

[image]

#### RegEx

You can modify/simplify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bV5gmS/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /^(.*?)([\s:]+)?{([\s\S].*)?.$/gm;
const str = `key:{value}
key:{valu{0}e}
key:{valu
{0}e}
key:   {val-u{0}e}
key:  {val__[!]
-u{0}{1}e}`;
const subst = `$1,$3`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### C# Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"^(.*?)([\s:]+)?{([\s\S].*)?.$";
        string substitution = @"$1,$3";
        string input = @"key:{value}
key:{valu{0}e}
key:{valu
{0}e}
key:   {val-u{0}e}
key:  {val__[!]
-u{0}{1}e}";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```

#### Original RegEx Test

```js
const regex = /^(?<key>\w+?)\s*?:\s*?{(?<value>[\s\S]+?)}$/gm;
const str = `key:{value}
key:{valu{0}e}
key:{valu
{0}e}
key:   {val-u{0}e}
key:  {val__[!]
-u{0}{1}e}`;
const subst = `$1,$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### References:

- [String.replaceAll without RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316710/string-replaceall-without-regex/4316725#4316725)
- [C# regular expression match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740984/c-sharp-regex-matches-example)
- [Regular Expression Groups in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375873/regular-expression-groups-in-c-sharp)
- [c# regex matches example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740984/c-sharp-regex-matches-example)
- [Regex: How to get a group name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163344/regex-how-to-get-a-group-name/1163411#1163411)
- [How to use inline modifiers in C# regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542042/how-to-use-inline-modifiers-in-c-sharp-regex/3542048)
- [Regex to first match, then replace found matches](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119519/regex-to-first-match-then-replace-found-matches)